# Principal bundles with non-constant structure group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, connections, principal-bundles

Take $P \rightarrow M$ to be a principal $G$-bundle. We modify the bundle so the structure group $G$ is not the same for all fibres of the bundle.

Is there a name for such an object? Are there issues with modifying a principal bundle so the structure group is not constant?

It seems like there might be issues with defining trivializations for such a bundle. If there are, can they be overcome?

**Motivation**

Write $G = \text{SU} \left( 2 \right)$. In his paper "Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial", Witten considers Chern-Simons theory using a $G$-bundle $P \rightarrow \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a Riemann surface.

Next he considers when $\Sigma$ is punctured at points $z_i$. He argues that, to get the correct phase space using quantization, we must modify $P$ so that the structure group is $G$ for all fibres except at the puncture points $z_i$. Here he says the structure group must be reduced to $G/T$, where $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$.

Comment: There is the concept of "fibration", which is a generalization of fibre bundles where the fibres do not need to be the same, but just homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @G.Blaickner Indeed, but $G$ and $G/T$ are hardly going to be homotopy equivalent. :)

Comment: There are such objects and they are ubiquitous in the theory of group actions, but they are not (normally) called principal fiber bundles (they not even fibrations in many interesting cases). Yes, there are numerous issues one has to deal with when working with these, due to lack of local trivialization. One replaces local sections with *slices.* Take a look at Bredon's book "Introduction to Compact Transformation Groups". More generally, people study *Seifert fibrations* which do not necessarily come from group actions.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Kohan, I'll have a look through Bredon's book.